# `xsel` won't expand in one zsh but will in another

Tags: zsh

Many days ago, the zsh of my Arch Linux did what I want: if I entered `` `xsel` `` and pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it would be replaced by the output of `xsel`. Now, on the same box, I get this:

```
xsel: fstat error on stdin: Bad file descriptor
```

What's more strange, I have setup another Arch Linux now, with the same zsh and config files. It just does this expansion right.

I write a simple script `a` to discover what happens to the stdin:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $(readlink /proc/self/fd/0)
```

Let's try again---`` `./a` ``, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. On the former box, I get

```
pipe:\[4434444\]
```

and on the latter which is what I want:

```
/dev/pts/6
```

What should I do further to find out why they are different and get the expansion right?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out that this is caused by this [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) script sosurced from my `.zshrc` when available. I still don't know why this happens, but I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search/issues/13) for this.